# MATLAB - Smart way of reordering the data to show the bell shape?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of 810 doubles, which have a very good reason (not relevant, so reason left out here) to roughly follow a Gaussian distribution. I now wish to verify this.

```
-1425.35483258195
-2005.85887636008
1560.31387221920
422.221432204087
-396.336462872091
1028.04845220438
-126.818743685290
482.602336878657
-351.945829219904
-408.071209112604
-251.839429417447
-1325.82167938863
-1304.65143253464
984.905373772623
-866.213152797951
73.6149979242073
3834.52647065066
917.976216226379
815.189065312880
-96.0747513429396
-319.662630897599
-1221.53710722367
1190.72857085035
2144.87935230603
143.558912788403
-167.475218992091
84.4066585851642
604.944484054070
1509.18911810685
-587.472369780628
143.669853748808
-1412.71275982249
46.2128162171030
-141.952303144073
292.716350945286
-1952.97174976434
-391.978769841029
-573.922085615045
-1301.25783316103
-645.990154917124
-934.774832747395
116.250933690360
544.823087571245
160.470631259077
2602.37582436213
534.434360410673
989.338067269714
-447.272873139365
1118.95219395721
-898.345257943601
-681.176900874247
213.211488587428
-785.169609773158
-430.621935639622
-61.2013695948126
-377.605278281317
1497.99884427522
404.777865468637
-1504.27516707823
-789.565967187437
-1118.50469245357
665.045393010892
28.5870825819056
-1045.44580718356
409.712490593987
-772.727898866153
252.289204820367
-905.257023890462
-300.707805837961
-74.4828651478892
-1087.13018005821
275.455585388661
-947.372403119386
-348.098011249108
1645.59654581296
517.906791768635
322.688565166583
331.939567925477
-612.937714892369
1302.63905136005
-153.606350780020
962.124237023736
-627.507634881584
-226.761116511015
463.132204629023
-939.535480854969
1532.46771710064
222.343444164121
303.799291944722
1084.75952392675
856.849727349139
514.671849059982
-1655.41677124587
-127.246214481867
1734.57538636725
56.2555496894129
297.184996955808
386.823038887674
1353.32907458661
-2307.42128989437
654.140638203676
-1392.55190147038
-607.378457188426
2384.44806882885
2293.43321702051
47.3551805244424
746.478352537506
-938.994569192230
192.721071163348
-4.29989698278951
100.289121179456
812.825042468773
103.758682367813
-490.446548621378
-1339.81881565035
-595.379417250646
499.458821146142
765.412270843621
532.095358987890
-247.000541594816
-480.064780362965
316.263039414615
449.159830642379
1933.73501675200
52.4933985187945
3107.07754310984
218.560847122495
-575.905775870265
2124.73813469493
1272.05488997025
-777.848735713576
-1981.23363300488
-1677.42292095700
605.970193322080
-759.457775207884
-84.6880200736514
-825.486129072864
739.859927410010
781.960329365344
-77.4149957958771
57.2191392940895
-500.299306284041
-575.933520504403
-1402.37563293800
-164.380079314064
232.496199533151
-1150.91949913415
-76.7244722653677
-47.1854688325975
3140.15003755460
-1330.34731058125
145.959328309073
1600.84592274169
-24.9232437067194
1395.72597116652
1621.21780908032
85.7934267467826
3279.93389739169
1516.36196103567
-1039.08123306694
-26.8801938594925
1492.40185616989
2445.00749952465
356.999233644735
962.558708481810
52.1166636462876
-180.338443931614
1135.86865368933
-823.056149900716
513.081279614810
1632.55462408653
700.098711621567
-1004.01052033257
838.798263982723
49.8997525149898
55.7119287736441
70.2170006303140
1694.63693249428
340.232240670027
-785.266479583255
-1490.75705865048
907.610252998604
-338.053785111386
-158.302237129483
810.050487377534
357.250435108372
-963.243345806145
-514.816899574995
-110.692584354545
-523.919862464934
1179.10220528566
-707.786358763919
-744.020374418825
-184.772566675096
1048.29906053004
291.212627519886
-1699.41811637976
1169.44527009486
-981.678801748923
-1003.40713607552
380.192537521396
-246.707457668937
550.802388031726
-537.288326878588
-1909.14320854900
334.084003654602
1315.91990144012
-87.7648557606226
484.711537732028
473.487768459009
-348.920356370175
1290.48676735822
128.895752577464
-463.231949345272
-461.975905174972
-1960.31200780286
-463.066933400454
636.123377337945
-457.893970268988
-886.605181442714
1288.19479205883
1534.45512372237
358.985063025987
-528.812332235894
-853.054006933991
-470.516697933259
75.7814123333455
922.488730629832
-607.322778020469
-1168.32280143675
-1164.49270789924
1144.46795817114
237.919069158304
464.605144587411
-1779.15853404145
-687.068044606544
-1558.76542615201
1122.67865170534
147.377599700542
-1941.99704382516
-197.265704116704
771.418343613877
617.611707163922
-184.024688145049
-630.977365935732
-1449.60039078064
-2031.87254125474
339.115574107012
507.110373028804
-35.3207932025325
-226.486793234861
-1151.56599554854
-1626.99321244231
137.738574478250
753.742389575134
254.480213830903
-299.494668002752
-464.217408373797
-496.881983902247
124.175797483519
641.036273039545
-875.645225304455
-850.013624134959
-1109.89290174708
-1564.11183301231
-697.565976576565
1033.07113738597
51.6226154312835
771.394497917418
942.389088995320
1196.05347790507
-678.014674370847
-1166.17784824523
-999.823651819537
401.157806208508
-477.448061210651
-73.4660915645727
354.733942551547
-431.951507899472
1318.88051933731
344.338765880639
598.804769543009
-1248.79480727276
858.421109550656
-556.899467429002
1807.63182070400
-159.136636488214
1799.22265828335
-240.692257347021
-1220.72830688348
74.1221061405495
-1640.11048850379
572.382227723556
94.5360732832287
-605.392031424351
-1493.66630795796
2797.18192240374
1616.53036000672
572.718159305989
-2204.37593002237
-322.774296955364
-430.000508898373
-104.048115418703
-1087.07923450010
-144.392429036394
-32.6087990828473
814.526216253877
-942.330594442485
561.790955470880
-919.551937169830
-637.665692814220
-27.5056243422514
-53.4289661228959
-349.487021035242
1254.06511966928
-1084.45861311495
2229.81290397501
-61.7348956711430
2315.31893617308
-905.051392195664
-330.066447009382
667.731590154659
2362.88627865678
-134.122103628698
-998.406485815768
3412.50099946158
1738.40741493709
-1435.63471165575
279.643055725084
-1080.07001067794
1038.67436238825
-59.5107168975392
-428.623061940542
90.9674755392625
428.864025012534
461.053414725420
76.7429752580429
-1047.74156835217
-1138.74437265796
-274.421370192137
-123.113141820210
1062.88624964445
-31.2932925583336
-47.2386460915968
566.285925381789
-162.476912673828
-579.149923138140
-1645.39762646152
-0.858506362164007
-1388.80667204739
-1611.24592897178
791.558877147674
-866.957703178365
-670.383595544925
-274.315832321348
832.836094551398
167.966896050509
-795.723924812035
-463.256974967680
1774.72662476188
565.080479736877
-567.419721200751
-1293.18551532982
-102.106516298420
-1023.45366146646
342.686949749701
-1943.95971161213
-1242.88726281114
-363.843860974623
218.911330607643
-1299.25729831318
1801.62607745420
485.598606188077
-209.745413876955
824.225434162006
80.4120792716949
-1101.71843965055
-489.648697328510
515.844053843147
921.482043018526
-1007.19911926667
892.329352367407
-206.559385161153
1289.34370927758
132.875816484038
-693.868519040030
1238.26425299907
-1029.59553086535
-1045.03807191815
684.486795552311
1156.78869170002
503.287695641337
-1761.08210583943
1504.49354570708
-2.38904808358893
-891.872139762875
-471.810563237261
-357.989880589008
1237.27821337192
-1118.74885097858
-1664.34130366938
-707.692351910793
-179.392901121722
2.51492953811066
1283.18737455847
-621.389601400035
-142.879999439187
409.670524550240
-1520.69976017121
-945.049848553859
-508.792922740967
-1013.16358819067
1333.23041683582
-485.612620083036
633.086691051391
974.147758083274
-1482.92064521016
170.457510166752
-319.276155374235
-102.475737807179
-806.147249075137
12.2710130392989
-1284.51556919452
-898.153118894255
-1264.39247941500
310.518406626345
300.653823915844
771.414870652903
-443.317509228219
-217.820334710797
-568.546664318710
1221.84294901066
406.621006399999
1536.40526591371
-88.1133675293550
-423.424777451501
911.889602982767
-561.496263588238
271.138351172729
-853.973387287833
-919.890778546460
29.2848487526380
515.153053644342
916.906990841340
-988.795430988675
-2288.39552282448
-354.278819283692
727.755387319324
-438.729779965080
-460.743800289783
498.419836651718
-1016.52550793176
1719.96686296631
1378.78460794700
-74.1662909720290
-794.313252330921
-579.575585572261
1032.38039003017
-139.352044190169
-921.411154727281
-632.436686005542
511.937665864214
-465.867561162771
682.753565100946
-837.343300398131
-203.807199334120
697.210075868778
383.665875798750
-285.949563188691
473.458597852185
-1074.35861318824
-1397.97178609897
-1003.88094273428
711.645485233387
980.242460658460
-528.721307121879
105.957921554011
-688.634132580983
-1639.86682075114
-1477.62683757162
462.025696610903
398.670153266179
-553.384968966910
625.057323419982
1002.74945530885
493.980588087071
738.959303162354
-1262.67475377973
-572.177811667752
308.236783523600
-406.525047730467
-279.064813326399
-958.715002126351
667.070145627578
101.287176877154
1029.77737241096
884.572701132805
-83.2129981675607
436.454402083900
-731.784460332883
-828.152649525027
-4.59039366284560
1173.27675925715
947.875960433114
219.825903925695
-1348.62640205386
1416.03397544099
-867.559504844558
-921.730092961659
-594.959474993817
-578.601607691280
1713.94162285846
-890.538205788453
-31.1520768075825
-840.083103895247
271.138757797886
30.4852851688702
1077.87779754491
1027.97848743209
-1216.23657331206
718.721023399901
1168.72555297803
-1126.29889111422
-38.0485352514261
559.324906271146
143.737128536855
-520.823282690490
-421.404810071988
-879.950358622646
383.976795499795
431.651954748570
-1014.23132627610
791.227060578848
-446.251570984076
-880.263297275125
249.601560953378
598.668996636698
-850.966552797904
-755.673152069518
572.459612333701
177.692884397484
600.926582295822
1188.77012356426
-691.839959588951
-502.690126011454
25.3399035825159
-520.840003827040
-1012.71789390801
389.607229075335
2336.37944482949
4601.28549891861
-306.109062155709
-549.754157876436
1366.49195319864
80.1658288538984
-371.898746055809
221.220689352235
-1034.26423624067
-227.175386588575
456.976283321366
-893.331715773963
1139.45199359176
-426.972252590305
125.689745639213
-755.291604557464
906.715046470356
-512.375090745554
-183.436523634227
-1271.17935524883
343.944597498092
357.375062083205
503.360088312412
-1063.47172123093
-544.151922949868
-811.465116940168
-382.518818090521
-556.364297944514
28.4462104060804
-391.469958695141
702.920945890725
3276.75393467650
-1601.46189476513
215.094152272832
1289.65287462539
-266.279004487831
-359.857620157932
770.042919144449
984.724775247226
-124.345016575689
-479.520031553426
-477.614657604774
-88.1973812779706
112.358632460992
-1213.83458979284
-2164.47382612438
68.3193891329520
-881.771368628023
169.849935188382
988.964748477654
158.420971886695
199.625846049925
-532.329781433098
-35.8791437174177
1327.24414199818
562.056024879379
-476.849700670497
221.935429478316
1563.51220970406
-799.111728532053
451.956789308570
-271.333350632898
637.294349346712
1842.67665511535
1462.24940915688
632.600524370893
-400.567297177738
-423.141178019932
-599.578935046919
1631.33084732187
1274.89043581579
417.304963875531
-1671.85306193716
-875.134111594071
-888.175742491925
781.420136563384
-267.891345155953
-984.747911033292
619.692042477853
507.097508348636
-2191.61648965449
871.941679622509
354.805731581013
-813.842611493990
-797.177241995762
-963.636395691701
69.1304461321361
-504.047776578296
2120.31188847033
-972.664353788443
1635.59419926198
813.341563425280
556.176646947061
853.969583042162
-340.944807273296
1860.51180529648
164.584505357234
2416.65258964103
453.392895539603
-598.129522562993
-436.423805800641
-1073.09763119235
818.515189790920
915.328394918082
-844.856562790346
-151.573550264624
188.640708868880
662.302131098894
599.417211331797
625.005959399488
-712.457731270164
-456.930434881017
430.006802672571
432.201988090676
-1805.76017728314
-765.777546844394
-366.775473893042
-1390.36840812369
-115.821548189160
-348.024152316248
-2081.96568815380
-1270.09386919888
590.375306666686
-1425.53765935045
3082.54680185326
127.134922589132
-64.8286220730133
1030.02663234355
814.903512139286
209.749857774112
-195.505605537004
-627.329338981148
-1312.39013357494
171.133025716999
1247.87792775840
-519.610915373372
2112.46320371606
9.32989625287883
165.878608899171
-1271.10665412487
-993.973494489265
2.05541319826716
-659.015889529154
1013.38348492602
719.325793086795
-533.063499513220
-120.770138644812
582.042029894734
-2453.18073103871
-480.093187602034
-947.472900692303
661.481266970943
2091.75056688107
264.617458558831
688.572625188444
-553.727400183363
1854.09100161690
-584.441964107862
160.859971291589
-721.797012172758
530.747141338406
-440.327138191801
110.306408202837
-1383.45033522105
-2165.65821622627
771.596558585712
168.287995174270
873.750929372014
-899.896768600454
826.404866814517
-954.055096167494
24.5476499542792
-1035.13149902373
242.010718795495
817.365138698160
-191.375310710834
1026.53362477036
1506.65413148945
-527.047853871006
-301.653867464794
-906.675209444651
-1.35693695415011
-1361.35311995217
-1055.16027830381
1835.99350558714
-153.771963586896
-1024.20571742302
-7.52437658966574
-199.706148737951
-55.6970184322190
358.588943940760
750.748910025249
-130.369658412103
115.801978429215
-362.228245710698
1072.90727368639
285.144147030216
275.476205540914
-425.410694245723
-358.251651764280
54.5762606959333
-986.393501781955
1987.82942003996
-119.612618624157
4088.87885652650
-46.4155713632708
855.384197547839
348.442497861890
-638.248417658654
1464.23877404674
1958.52428386456
102.248039598800
-111.573563229895
-485.111192525760
-766.212536691707
-2000.03833099073
-1256.32241772728
-42.4379799861126
664.131166310975
-801.923373300931
-983.323933269528
1648.18557989817
387.963306334943
-1569.93080059318
222.937758757887
-114.704995616332
-390.835557576743
-583.648071221651
898.816929040312
-1430.89073677080
485.974041322305
-546.204265548018
-928.957012051962
857.876890609405
275.037960659607
-984.994405754642
-2584.59906037955
-1238.24519741587
2252.11593175793
-615.096425393547
-1441.41851657964
1852.82338381085
-794.909638822273
-1724.84781684101
-837.605831849087
242.111467511679
-1348.52499237212
1575.34223230675
-1400.44850343094
2640.09986069654
-1216.91897365897
-861.181602306838
264.540049874899
722.940025618886
394.150610960769
-918.913133715832
-448.520560840232
169.730666854386
-553.694315285847
-389.285749031319
1917.29156813389
```

Since the vector is not ordered, directly plotting them in current order gives a messy plot like this.

[image]

What is a smart way of easily reordering the data so that I can verify whether they roughly follow a normal distribution or not?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `histogram` ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Oh my god. I am so stupid... Thanks a lot! Should I delete this question then? *facepalm*

Comment: @FarticlePilter it might be appropriate to delete the question...

Comment: Well I'd delete this question if I'd posted it, but it's really up to you, it's no worse than 75% of the questions on SO.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Too late... Since it already has answers, I can't delete it myself. I have flagged it though, leaving it to the moderators to decide. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if your data follow a Gaussian distribution you can use [`normplot`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/normplot.html). It draws the empirical distribution function of the data on a scale such that a Gaussian corresponds to a straight line. The more straight the line is, the more similar to a Gaussian.

If often happens that the curve is straight in the central part, and deviates on its ends. That's the case with your data; see figure below.

The explanation is that the Gaussian distribution usually arises from a sum of random variables, by virtue of the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). The distribution of the sum is Gaussian in the *limit* as the number of summands tends to infinity. For a *finite* number of terms the distribution is only *approximately* Gaussian; and the approximation is *better at the center* than on the tails (in fact, that's why the theorem is called *central*).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you could also run one of the hypothesis tests, like the [Jarque-Bera Test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/jbtest.html), which will tell you (within a confidence limit) how likely it is that your points were drawn from a normal distribution.

```
[h, p] = jbtest(X, 0.05);
if h
    disp(sprintf('There is less than %.3f%% chance that your data is abnormal', 100 * p));
else
    disp(sprintf('Your data is not normal within your confidence limit'));
end
```

This doesn't give you a pretty plot, but it will give you a less biased answer than just eyeballing it.

In this case, there is better than 99.9% chance that your data set was drawn from a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) function:

```
histogram(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

To view the PDF you can use:

```
if exist('histogram','func')
  histogram(data)
else
  hist(data)
end
```

This looks pretty normal to me. You can always try modeling it with a gaussian.

[image: histogram]

Comment: Well yes, but `hist` has been deprecated in favour of `histogram`.

Comment: histogram is a new function. I am still on R2012 so thanks for the update! Answer has been appended